# JavaScript infinite loop upon clicking "Next" button

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, firebug

Been a while since I last did JavaScript, but school forced us into a JavaScript project. So here I am, making a simple quiz game. Coming along quite nicely, yet I'm experiencing issues with probably something terribly simple.

```
var useranswers = new Array();
var imgArray = new Array();
var answered = 0;
var currentQuestion = 0;

function renderQuizViaArray() 
{
    document.writeln('<h1>' + questions[currentQuestion] + '</h1>');

    for(i=0; i < choices[currentQuestion].length; i++)
    {
        document.writeln('<input type="radio" name="answer_' + currentQuestion + '" value="1" id="answer_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '" class="question_' + currentQuestion + '" onclick="submitAnswer(' + currentQuestion + ', this, \'question_' + currentQuestion + '\', \'label_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '\')" /><label id="label_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '" for="answer_' + currentQuestion + '_' + i + '"> ' + choices[currentQuestion][i] + '</label><br />');
    }

    document.write('<input type="submit" value="NEXT" onclick="nextQuestion()" />');
}

function nextQuestion()
{
    currentQuestion++;
    renderQuizViaArray();
}
```

Whenever I click the "NEXT" button, it loads the second question (Element[1]) from an Array as well as the answers of another Array onto the screen. But the page remains in an infinite loading state and Firebug gives the message: "Reload to activate window console"

Anyone?

Comment: Don't use `document.write` If you must, simply concatenate that HTML to the body tag's `innerHTML` property value. Also, that isn't an infinite loop.

Comment: What's the content of `choices[currentQuestion]`? Shouldn't that be `i < choices.length`?
It's probably that for loop generating a infinite loop.
@Asad Aside from the fact that `innerHTML` is evil, too ;)

Comment: No no, choices[currentquestion] is a string so it is correct

Comment: @Cerbrus That depends on what the value of choices is. If `choices[index]` is an array (or anything else with a length), everything is fine. In fact, there won't be an infinite loop even if there is no length property, because `i<undefined == true` for all integers.

Comment: yeah i suppose this is an array containing all the possible answers

Comment: A jsfiddle reproducing the problem would definitely help there.

Comment: Please show where you are defining `choices` and `questions`

Comment: Hey wait you are calling some other functions like submit_answers, i can't find anything wrong on this code so the problem might come from this func. If this func got a syntax error or any other problem, the code will stop and firebug ask for a review, you have your solution

Comment: quiz.html: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c326115cKAUf6S.png ........ quiz_questions.js: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c536ed44UWhV54.png ......... quiz_functions.js: Shown in main post

Answer (score 0):

I have probably found the issue, but no idea how to fix it.

As soon as I click the "NEXT" button, it executes the function renderQuizViaArray();. That's where it's completely messing up.. am I missing something?

What I basically want is, that the current displayed text gets updated with data of the next question including the answers.

These are the files it contains:
quiz.html: http://rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c326115cKAUf6S.png ........ quiz_questions.js: http://rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c536ed44UWhV54.png ......... quiz_functions.js: Shown in main post

Answer (score -1):

don't use

```
for(i=0; i < choices[currentQuestion].length; i++)
```

use

```
for(i=0, j=choices[currentQuestion].length; i < j; i++)
```

Comment: this is a better coding solution but i doubt it'll resolve the problem, but i'm not so good in js, so please, surprise me

Comment: If you're correcting something useless, at least do it correctly :) (`var`)

Comment: I think loop is created by choices[currentQuestion].length, because length is increased everytime you run function inside loop. This sets length value to variable and prevents infinite loop.

Comment: why is the lenght increased ? if the array contain 3 possible answers, i doubt this value will change, you are only preventing multiple calculation of the length

Comment: I don't know where array choices comes from since OP didn't show it in example. But i do see that in function inside loop there is something like variables called currentQuestion. That makes me think that choices[currentQuestion].length is increased in loop, which creates infinite loop.

Comment: @MattiMehtonen: the `currentQuestion++;` is to iterate throught different choices. that's not the source of the error, since the `++` isn't executed in the loop.

Comment: I will answer with an image link, as adding comments doesn't allow much characters.. :S http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9abdad9b0u5fH2h.png (don't pay attention to the questions, that's solely a sample)

Comment: I don't see how that data could result in a loop.
The data is structured correctly, and there's not funny business in the loop (aside from the `document.write`, but that's unrelated)

Comment: Copied from above: quiz.html: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c326115cKAUf6S.png ........ quiz_questions.js: http://www.rapidimg.org/server/files/50ab9c536ed44UWhV54.png ......... quiz_functions.js: Shown in main post

Comment: I have probably found the issue, but no idea how to fix it.

As soon as I click the "NEXT" button, it executes the function renderQuizViaArray();. That's where it's completely messing up..

What I basically want is, that the current displayed text gets updated with data of the next question including the answers.